# Remote ssh commad with variables, quotes and single quotes

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters, mongodb

I need to execute a command on a remote MongoDB server, using variables declared on the shell script.

**Command:**

```
ssh root@10.1.1.1 "mongo mydb --host 10.1.1.1 --port 27017 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.mycollection.update({}, {$push: {'"$ENTITY"': NumberInt('"$CODE"')}})' --quiet"
```

Note that if I use the command outside the shell script, substituting the variables, a bash -c syntax error comes up. Example:

```
ssh root@10.1.1.1 "mongo mydb --host 10.1.1.1 --port 27017 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.mycollection.update({}, {$push: {foo: NumberInt(123)}})' --quiet"

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

It's working now! **Solution:**

```
DBUPDATE="db.mycollection.update({}, {\$push: {${ENTITY}: NumberInt(${CODE})}})"

ssh root@10.1.1.1 mongo mydb --host 10.1.1.1 --port 27017 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "'$DBUPDATE'" --quiet
```

Comment: What does the command return?

Comment: It returns an error from MongoDB: `SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell eval)`.

Comment: What are the contents of your variables?

Comment: @sebasth those variables are arguments of the script (e.g. test.sh foo 123). Note that the mongo command works as intended, just not working when I use it with ssh due to the quotes.

Comment: Put the shell commands in a script on the remote host and call that script through SSH.

Comment: Yes @Kusalananda that would be a solution, but I did not want to create unnecessary dependencies. I already found out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh root@10.1.1.1 'mongo mydb --host 10.1.1.1 --port 27017 -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.mycollection.update({}, {$push: {'"$ENTITY"': NumberInt('"$CODE"')}})" --quiet'
```

I switched the double quotes with single quotes at the beginning and end and put your `--eval` input in double quotes.

Comment: It returns the same error: `SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell eval)`